# Add active class on page change in the menu bar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, menu

I have this menu with ul and li and child uls. When an user clicks and moves to the linked page, I want to set an active class so that that menu item is highlighted. Since the page changes, I am saving the clicked menu li id in the local storage and using that info to highlight the menu item. 
Here is my code so far-

```
$(function() {
$('li.main').click(function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('thisLink', $(this).attr("data-id"));
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.navbar-brand').click(function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('thisLink', 'dashboard');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // window relaod  fix on logout
    // return "Hello";
}

thisLink = localStorage.getItem('thisLink');
if (thisLink) {
    $('#' + thisLink).addClass('active');
}
});
```

HTML menu structure:

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li data-id="dashboard" id="dashboard" class="main">
                        <a class="" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="icon-grid"></i>
                            <span class="">
                                Dashboard
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-id="users" id="users" class="main">
                        <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="icon-user"></i>
                            <span class="">
                                Users
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="true" class="">
                            <li><a href="UserList">List User</a></li>
                            <li><a href="AddUser">Add User</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-id="user-role" id="user-role" class="main">
                        <a class="" href="Groups" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="icon-shuffle"></i>
                            <span class="">
                                Users Role
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <li data-id="product" id="product" class="main">
                        <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="icon-tag"></i>
                            <span class="">
                                Product
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="true" class="">
                            <li><a href="category">View Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="subcategory">View Subcategory</a></li>
                            <li><a href="size">View Size</a></li>
                            <li><a href="color">View Color</a></li>
                            <li><a href="brand">View Brand</a></li>
                            <li><a href="prolist">List Product</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Product">Add Product</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-id="configuration" id="configuration" class="main">
                        <a class="" href="Settings" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="icon-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="">
                                Configuration
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?> 
                    <li data-id="backup" id="backup" class="main">
                        <a class="" href="backupdb" aria-expanded="false">
                           <i class="icon-arrow-down-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="">
                                Backup
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

It's a dynamic site and the problem is if the user logs out and logs in again, the dashboard is shown but the highlighted item remains the last menu clicked and saved in the localstorage. And I have to specify ID for each menu item only for this purpose, which makes the solution too hacky.
What is a smarter solution in JS/jQuery? Or PHP is the only solution?

Comment: Clear the localstorage item when the user logs out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kerbholz. Is this procedure a standard practice?

Comment: And if a user closes the browser tab while any sub-menu is set as active and he comes back and the dashboard loads as by default (home), it shows the last visited sub-menu as active.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just take the URL of the page, and do a quick lookup from it?

Something like:

```
jQuery('nav.sidebar-nav li:has(a[href="'+ window.location.pathname +'"])').addClass('activeMenuItem');
```

Comment: I tried that and there is a problem. I have submenus. The second level LIs each have different root level URL. They run as follows-

ul
  li url=firstpage
  li url=none, default prevented
    ul
       li url=secondpage
       li url=thirdpage
       ...
  li url=fourthpage

So pathname==secondpage || pathname = thirdpage will add activeClass to its parent defaultPrevented LI. For seven sub-li's, I'll have to write seven OR logic. I am not sure if it is a good way as I am repeating myself. Is it the standard way?

(I indented the ul>li structure above but stackoverflow inlined it)